# Issue with printing long receipts with java print() on thermal printer

Tags: java, printing, receipt

I cannot print a thermal receipt (8cm) beyond (almost) A4 height paper size. Program only prints till (some default almost) A4 size is reached. and rest of receipt is lost.

Everything works fine with smaller receipts. problem occurs only with long receipts, where bill is cut short. I dynamically set paper height counting the lines to print. I also tried setting paper size and imageablearea to big size manually but in vain.

I tried to use `Print.Book` class object as well with no improvement.

(Note: Another program written in another language, prints same bill fine on same printer)

Please let me know if I am missing something or how to remove this limitation.

```
public void printReciept()
    {        
        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();        
        pj.setPrintable(new BillPrintable(),getPageFormat(pj));
        try {
             pj.print();

        }
         catch (PrinterException ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




public PageFormat getPageFormat(PrinterJob pj)
{

    PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
    Paper paper = pf.getPaper();    

    double middleHeight =this.productList.size()*1.0;  //dynamic----->change with the row count of jtable
    double headerHeight = 5.0;                  //fixed----->but can be mod
    double footerHeight = 5.0;                  //fixed----->but can be mod

    double width = convert_CM_To_PPI(8);      //printer know only point per inch.default value is 72ppi
    double height = convert_CM_To_PPI(headerHeight+middleHeight+footerHeight); 
    paper.setSize(width, height);
    paper.setImageableArea(                    
        0,
        10,
        width,            
        height - convert_CM_To_PPI(1)
    );   //define boarder size    after that print area width is about 180 points

    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);           //select orientation portrait or landscape but for this time portrait
    pf.setPaper(paper);    

    return pf;
}




public class BillPrintable implements Printable {


 @Override
  public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat,int pageIndex) 
  throws PrinterException 
  {    
        String title[] = {"Product Name","Disc","Rate","Qty","AMT"};      
        int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;    
        if (pageIndex == 0) {                    

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;                

            g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(),(int) pageFormat.getImageableY()); 

            ***** Below will be Code to print bill records *****
   }
}
```